# Changing manifest installLocation parameter on updates

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-update-app

Does anyone know what the impact of changing the Android Manifest setting

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

to

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

on an UPDATE to an already installed app for a user? I'm worried about people who may have moved the app to external storage post initial install - or is this setting ignored on updates?

Comment: They won't be able to update if they have it on the SD card. I think Lollipop and later forbid this behavior no matter what, though.

Comment: Thank, just for clarity, what 'behaviour' do they forbid specifically?

Comment: Installing apps to the SD card.

Comment: Hmm. Where's your source for that pls? Nothing to suggest restriction on lollipop+ on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#install